# how to add fix number of rows to gridview in c#?

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms, aspxgridview

I have to insert fix number of rows to gridview. I am not using database and also not creating row one by one.

I initially want 7 rows with 3 column, with first column having text stored in my array.

I am creating gridview as,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Height="146px"
        OnLoad="row_created" Width="308px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Day" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Available rooms">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not creating a class object then bind it to the grid, set default values for `index` to display it as `Row Number`, and all other members `Day, price and Rooms` filled back from user

something like:

```
 class MyObject
  {
     public int Index { get; set; }
     public string Day { get; set; }
     public decimal Price { get; set; }
     public string Rooms { get; set; }
   }
```

use it like this

```
List<MyObject> lst = new List<MyObject>();
lst.Add(new MyObject { Index = 1});
lst.Add(new MyObject { Index = 2});
```

p.s.: Names and usage is just for explaining the idea

Comment: Only day column is having data, price and available rooms will get through user from textbox

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that.

Some ways are either to create a DataTable and insert the data into it, and then bind it to the GridView.

A better solution would be to create objects with your data, store them in some sort of a collection(List or array will do), and then bind your collection to the DataGrid.
If you don't want to create a class for this, you can use anonymous types.

Comment: I need to insert data into only 1st column and other columns are having textboxes

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggested solution:

- Define the data-source for the grid as a data-table
- And just change the structure of the data-table object and rebind to the grid, as applicable
- Example:-

==>

```
public partial class WebPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected DataTable GridSource
{
        get {   return ViewState["GridSource"] as DataTable;    }
        set 
        {   
            ViewState["GridSource"] = value;

            gridViewControl.DataSource = value;
            gridViewControl.DataBind();
        }
}

private void AddRow(DataRow row)
{
    // Get the lastly binded structure and data
    DataTable tableSource = this.GridSource;

    // Add row to data-table "tableSource"
    //..

    // Apply the new structure and data
    this.GridSource = tableSource;
}

// .. Add relevant implementation (methods) for remove, modify operations
//.. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered the same problem .. This tutorial helped me solve my prob .. You can check it out ..
http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/04/adding-dynamic-rows-in-gridview-with-textboxes.aspx